# How to split a rasterized image into multiple pieces?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to split a rasterized image into several distinct parts. For example, in the below photo, I want to divide the imaege into three sections so when they are arranged together, they exactly create the original image. [image]

I can't figure out how to do this. In illustrator, it is easy to do with vector graphics, but I can't figure out how to split it in a non simple way for a rasterized image. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's a raster image.. I'd use Photoshop. Illustrator is simply not designed to make rater editing an easy thing.

Comment: Well, this depends **a lot** on what you mean by exactly. There are many reasons why exact may or may not be all that exact after all. So if you intend to assemble the images on a computer then clipping mask is not as exact as youd think (neither is an alpha mask since things dont work the way people expect them to work). Conversely if you intend to physically assemble them later then clipping exactly on the line may not be the best thing to do. Youd get a much better answer on exactly once you define the usecase.

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator, probably the easiest way would be to use clipping masks.

Use some guides to help you, then draw three closed shapes, and duplicate the image layer three times.  Then apply each shape as a clipping mask to each of the three copies of the image.

An example

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the respnse, Billy! My real question is how to make it so that the pieces of the image are perfect/near perfect "reciprocals" of each other. In other words I want them to share a boundary. So by definition, the line where one ends is the line where the other starts. Could you please explain if there's a way to do that?

Comment: @IlanBerdy - do you mean in Photoshop? TBH it might be harder since you will likely end up with anti-aliasing (a visible line) between the pieces as shown in the by another user here. Using Illustrator is probably your best bet, as it handles this problem better.

Comment: Either Illustrator or Photoshop work. My main point of confusion is how to divide the picture so that the border for one piece is also a border for the other piece, as opposed to just drawing another line in about the same place. Thanks for your thoughtful responses!

Comment: @IlanBerdy - use guides, and snapping.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it must be done in Photoshop (as you have tagged) creates easily some difficulties. Using the polygon lasso to make a selection or converting a path to selection leaves an antialiasing zone where something can be seen through:

[image]

Above your image has been split to 2 parts by making a selection and by cutting & pasting (in place) the selected half to a new layer. The anti-alias zone has some transparency in both halves. Layering them doesn't produce an opaque image, the white background can still be seen.

I guess you know this already. Obviously you have also noticed that making the selection with antialiasing unchecked nor refining the selection edge to 100% contrast, zero smoothness and zero feathering don't fix it completely, there's still some transparency. So, some better ideas are needed.

One way is to use the pencil, the surely pixel perfect tool in Photoshop.

Insert a new layer. Draw there with the pencil the division line. Hold shift at the endpoints to get a straight line. The pencil is 4px wide:

[image]

Fill with the paint bucket one of the halves. Demand contiguous fill, zero tolerance and no anti-alias:

[image]

The fill is pixel perfect. Make with it a pixel perfect selection by clicking the filled layer icon in the layers panel and by holding the Ctrl key at the same time. Uncheck the anti-aliasing option!

Cut and paste in place the selected half from the image:

[image]

As you see, there's no background (nor underlying red) ghost. The division line goes just in the midpoint of my screenshot.

I splitted the image only to 2 parts. Nothing prevents making more complex borders nor splitting the halves again.

**Note:** Raster images are always rectangles, the invisible part is only transparent. There's no way to make the transparent pixels non-existent. That's true also in Illustrator. There you may hide a part of the image with a clipping or opacity mask, but the rest of the rectangle is still there and can be seen occasionally when the item is selected or the mouse hovers on it. Only pure vector objects can be at the same time non-rectangular and without hidden parts in Illustrator.